# JWT - Always unauthorized

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have a very simple code for the user to login as following:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel model)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            if (user != null && await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
            {
                var userRoles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

                var authClaims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                };

                foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
                {
                    authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
                }

                var authSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:Secret"]));

                var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: _configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                    audience: _configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
                    claims: authClaims,
                    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                    );

                return Ok(new
                {
                    token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                    expiration = token.ValidTo
                });
            }
            return Unauthorized();
        }
```

**This sends me the token as expected**

[image: Token Image]

When I use the Token to send a request to a simple controller I get 401-Unauthorized

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getme")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        return Ok("Good");
    }
}
```

[image: postman]

This is my Startup.cs

```
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnStr")));

    // For Identity
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(o =>
    {
        // configure identity options
        o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    // Adding Authentication
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })

    // Adding Jwt Bearer
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:Secret"]))
        };
    });
```

and the following is my appsettings
[image: appsettings]

I can verify the token at https://jwt.io/
[image: jwt.io]

For some reason when I send a request to `TestController` it always sends back an Unauthorized response. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using a *symmetric* key for signing? Are you seeing any exceptions or logs that can tell you why the 401 is returned?

Comment: Do you really need the `options.SaveToken`? Have you tried without that?

Comment: One easy way to debug btw is to break inside `OnAuthenticationFailed`: `options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents() { OnAuthenticationFailed = c => { return Task.CompletedTask; } };`. Should be called if the token is deemed invalid (but I don't think it's called if the token is completely missing).

Comment: @StephenCleary I thought it was a safer option but I am pretty much new to JWT so please advice why not to use a symmetric key for signing - >Leaky  to fix the issue I had to use Authentication > Routing > Authorization in that sequence, my Authorization was before Authentication which caused the issue

Comment: If you have a symmetric key, then the consumer of the JWT can also produce JWTs whenever it wanted. Technically it would work (assuming you control both the JWT producer and consumer), but it increases your attack surface area (instead of hardening just your JWT producer, you'd have to harden all your APIs to the same degree).

Comment: Thanks, @StephenCleary is there an article you can refer me to for more details? This is interesting and I would love more information on it, I had these thoughts when building this API but then the idea of JWT having 3 part key, overcame. Would love to know more about other possible options with JWT

Comment: @Ali: Nothing other than the book Applied Cryptography. JWTs have 3 parts, not a "3 part key".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this helps anyone, The issue was in my `Startup` file under `Configure` section I had `UseAuthentication` after `UseAuthorization` which cause the issue. The correct order as following fixed the issue

```
app.UseAuthentication(); 
app.UseRouting(); 
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Comment: imho, `app.UseHttpsRedirection(); ` should be the first middleware here. with current order there can be exchange of tokens via unencrypted channel